# Next.js explosion of crawlable files

Tags: next.js, seo

So we deployed an app to production and once we started getting traffic on the page we saw an explosion in crawlable pages (with audisto) and also in the search console. A lot of these pages are not actual pages but rather pages like:

`_next/static/chunks/415-346ff9ef0019b4be.js` or
`_next/data/lPuQfW-esUIlgkYvK94Ur/de/product/dishwasher-tabs-80-loads.json`

Should we add those files to robots.txt or what is the best practice to exclude them from being crawled? Excluding them from robots seems quite excessive/radical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same problem here...
Dont know if it's related to a nextjs (using 12.0.8 stable) or a google search console update

1. Easy fix would be to denied access to _next/data in robots.txt but it is a radical way.
   [image]
2. Does it hurt SEO ?
   With now several weeks of hindsight I am less worried about the degradation of SEO ranking.
   I don't think it will have a negative impact on crawling credits.

The requests are categorized (Googlebot Type) as "Page resource load".
According to this page https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9679690?hl=en , these requests are a secondary fetch :

> Page resource load: A secondary fetch for resources used by your page. When Google crawls the page, it fetches important linked resources such as images or CSS files, in order to render the page before trying to index it. This is the user agent that makes these resource requests.

[image]

In the absence of visible impact I do not modify the robots.txt rules

Answer (score 1):

Once a first page is loaded in the browser, there are two ways to load further pages when a user clicks a link:

1. Download them pages from the server (SSR/SSG).
2. Download the relevant JS and render them in the browser (CSR).

A browser will JS enabled will do 2. Because Googlebot supports JS, it will also do 2. It's not clear how well this works but I'm having problems with excluded pages. It seems to me that Googlebot is getting bogged down exploring the JS version of the site, so I'm going to try exluding /_next/ in the robots.txt and see if that forces to explore the site as a collection of static pages.